# Getting ID related to another ID in table then using the ID to get information from another table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I am going to try and explain this the best way I can. I have a table called albumAccess which has the following fields : id, albumID, userID, and permission.

Next I have another table that holds information for each album based off of the albumID.

I want to know how I can use the userID to get all of the album information. I have been researching joins and php arrays but not sure how to go about doing it.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You seem very new to SQL.  This is a fundamental SQL operation called a `join`.  I would suggest you learn a bit about databases.

Comment: I know about Joins but I know simple joins such as getting one thing of information to match. this is a tad bit more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking the another table name as albumDetails that holds information for each album based off of the albumID.

```
select albumAccess.*, albumDetails.* from albumAccess, albumDetails where
albumAccess.albumID=albumDetails.albumID and 
albumAccess.userID=YOUR_REQUIRED_USER_ID
```

Comment: this seems close but all I have generally is the user ID. From that I need to get all of the album IDs associated with it, then get all the album info for each album ID

Comment: Oh, it is so sad when old-style joins are chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard without a syntax to work with but i think something like this could work.

```
SELECT 
tablea.*,
tableb.*
FROM albumaccess        tablea
JOIN albuminfo          tableb ON tablea.AlbumId=tableb.AlbumId
WHERE tablea.UserId='theuserid'
```

This will JOIN rows matching on AlbumId.

Comment: this seems close but all I have generally is the user ID. From that I need to get all of the album IDs associated with it, then get all the album info for each album ID

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for.

SELECT * FROM `users` u, `albuminfos` ai, `albumaccesses` aa WHERE aa.user_id=u.id

Comment: this seems close but all I have generally is the user ID. From that I need to get all of the album IDs associated with it, then get all the album info for each album ID